# Js switch statement construction

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using apps script/ES5. I have:

```js
function returnText(message) {
  switch(message.indexOf(mykey)!== -1) {
  case true:
    var mykey = 'ziptest'  
    break;
  case true:
    var mykey = 'setnum' 
    break;
  default:
      console.log('default');
  }
}

function returnText1() {
  returnText('ziptest 19886991201')
}

returnText1();
```

It defaults to the default option. How can I fix this so that it selects the option where:

```
  var mykey = 'ziptest'
```

Comment: Why do you have `case true` twice?

Comment: Use an `if-else` conditional for a boolean condition.

Comment: That is not how you use switch.

Comment: You are testing the value of `mykey` before you set it. So `undefined` is obviously not occurring in `message`.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I knew I was doing it wrong but wondered if there was a way to avoid resorting to if else statements :( - right now I have only 3 options but I might want to add 5-6 more later.

Comment: How  can you have 5 or 6 boolean options??

Comment: Beware that your accepted answer using `switch` is non-idiomatic, verbose, and not in any way more efficient than `if`/`else if`. Most JS programmers wouldn't even realize you can use `switch` that way, because `switch` doesn't work that way in many other languages that have `switch` (C, Java, C#...). I don't care what answer you accept, but I **strongly** urge you not to use `switch` that way.

Comment: @user61629 - *"right now I have only 3 options but I might want to add 5-6 more later"* Then you want a loop, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `switch` then you can do something like this.

```js
function returnText(message) {
  switch (true) {
    case message.indexOf('ziptest') > -1:
      console.log('ziptest');
      break;
    case message.indexOf('setnum') > -1:
      console.log('setnum');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('default');
  }
}

function returnText1() {
  returnText('ziptest 19886991201')
}

returnText1();
```

Comment: Surely no good reason. Just to show how to properly use improper tool.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how a `switch` statement works. The code in a JavaScript function is largely step-by-step, in order from beginning to end. The condition in `switch ()` is evaluated **once**, when that point of the code is reached.

If you want to check for two different strings in `message`, although you *could* use a `switch`, it would be inappropriate and confusing. Instead, use `if`/`else if`/`else`:

```
function returnText(message) {
    if (message.indexOf("ziptest")!== -1) {
        return "ziptest";
    } else if (message.indexOf("setnum") !== -1) {
        return "setnum";
    } else {
        return "default";
    }
}
```

(Since each branch `return`s, you don't actually need `else` there, but...)

---

In a comment you've said:

> right now I have only 3 options but I might want to add 5-6 more later

In that case, use a loop. If you could use ES2015+ features, I'd use `find`:

```
const strings = ["ziptest", "setnum", /*...*/];
function returnText(message) {
    return strings.find(str => message.indexOf(str) !== -1) || "default";
}
```

`find` returns the first entry for which the callback returns a truthy value (and stops looping), or `undefined` if it runs out of entries without the callback returning a truthy value. So with the above, we check each `str` returning `true` if the string exists in `message`. If `find` returns `undefined`, the `|| "default"` kicks in and supplies the default string instead.

But since you can't, you can use `some` as [TheMaster shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151722/157247), or just a simple loop:

```
var strings = ["ziptest", "setnum", /*...*/];
function returnText(message) {
    for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
        var str = strings[i];
        if (message.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
            return str;
        }
    }
    return "default";
}
```

---

Side note: I see you've tagged this [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), so you're probably stuck with `.indexOf(str) !== -1`. But I hear they're updating it, so you *might* have `.includes(str)` now.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use arrays, if you have many keys.

```js
var myKeys = ['ziptest', 'setnum'];
function returnText(message) {
  var selectKey;
  myKeys.some(function(key){
if(message.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
  selectKey = key;
  return true;
}
  })
  return selectKey;
  }

function returnText1() {
  return returnText('ziptest 19886991201')
}

console.log(returnText1());
```

Comment: Just FWIW, there's a built-in to do what your `some` construct above does: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. I saw in your answer. But Not supported yet in apps script. From the mdn methods list, of, from, find, findIndex,fill, includes, entries, copyWithin, flat, flatMap, keys, values are not yet supported. AFAIK, the rest are fully supported. Arrow functions are also not supported as yet.

Comment: I keep forgetting that `find` was ES2015, not ES5. :-)